# Name for a distribution between exponential and gamma?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, distribution-identification

The density $$f(s)\propto \frac{s}{s+\alpha}e^{-s},\quad s > 0$$ where $\alpha \ge 0$ is a parameter, lives between the exponential ($\alpha=0$) and $\Gamma(2,1)$ ($\alpha \to \infty$) distributions. Just curious if this happens to be an example of a more general family of distributions? I do not recognize it as such.

Answer (score 7):

The density function becomes 
$$
  f(s) = {\frac {\alpha}{1-2\,{{\rm e}^{\alpha}}{\it Ei} \left( 3,\alpha
 \right) }}\cdot \frac{s}{s+\alpha} e^{-s}, \quad s>0
$$
where ${\it Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Ei).

I cannot recognize that as something having a known name. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: I needed to define it in the course of working on problem in mathematical genetics. It would not surprise me to find that it is relatively unknown -- always good to double-check though!

Comment: This math search engine http://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24+%5Cfrac%7Bs%7D%7Bs%2B%5Calpha%7De%5E%7B-s%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=   do not find anything.

Comment: +1. Do you have any guidance as to how to profitably use this engine? I just tried https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=Gauss+%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7De%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dx%5E2%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=, which, imho, should return results...

Comment: @Cristoph Hanck: 1) seems like it requires registration now? 2) the syntax seems to be very strict. Following their first example `$E=mc^2$` gives no results, but  `${E=mc^2}$` works.